# Failed to register native method com.secneo.sdk.Helper.attach

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dji-sdk

I am following this tutorial https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html

After finishing the tutorial, I am getting an error that is caused by `Helper.install(MApplication.this)` . It looks like JNI cannot find a library or method, but I am not sure how to fix that. Any suggestions?

Error:

```
E/i.importSDKDem: ----- class 'Lcom/secneo/sdk/Helper;' cl=0x12d40560 -----
      objectSize=196 (172 from super)
      access=0x0008.0001
      super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
      vtable (0 entries, 11 in super):
      direct methods (2 entries):
         0: void com.secneo.sdk.Helper.<clinit>()
         1: void com.secneo.sdk.Helper.a(android.app.Application)
      static fields (6 entries):
         0: java.lang.String com.secneo.sdk.Helper.a
         1: java.lang.String com.secneo.sdk.Helper.b
         2: java.lang.String com.secneo.sdk.Helper.c
         3: java.lang.String com.secneo.sdk.Helper.d
         4: java.lang.String com.secneo.sdk.Helper.e
         5: android.content.Context com.secneo.sdk.Helper.f
    Failed to register native method com.secneo.sdk.Helper.attach(Landroid/app/Application;Landroid/content/Context;)V in /data/app/~~t5l2JrENqDtK9h63QUieEA==/com.dji.importSDKDemo-GFVSkrTLxiIA3Acvo_NODg==/base.apk
A/i.importSDKDem: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/secneo/sdk/Helper;.attach(Landroid/app/Application;Landroid/content/Context;)V"
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class) (Runtime.java:-2)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:1131)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1085)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1008)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1664)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void com.secneo.sdk.Helper.a(android.app.Application) (:41)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void com.dji.importSDKDemo.MApplication.attachBaseContext(android.content.Context) (:13)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.app.Application.attach(android.content.Context) (Application.java:351)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at android.app.Application android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Context) (Instrumentation.java:1159)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at android.app.Application android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(boolean, android.app.Instrumentation) (LoadedApk.java:1236)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:6683)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:237)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1913)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:223)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7656)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:592)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:947)
    java_vm_ext.cc:577] 
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]     in call to FindClass
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class)
A/i.importSDKDem: oat_quick_method_header.h:91] Check failed: code_size_ != 0xFFFFFFFF (code_size_=4294967295, 0xFFFFFFFF=4294967295) 4294967295
A/i.importSDKDem: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
    runtime.cc:655] #00 pc 00542d9e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+110)
    runtime.cc:655] #01 pc 0063988a  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2026)
    runtime.cc:655] #02 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
    runtime.cc:655] #03 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
    runtime.cc:655] #04 pc 00006291  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_call_aborter+33)
    runtime.cc:655] #05 pc 00014d14  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+436)
    runtime.cc:655] #06 pc 001d2a4c  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::OatQuickMethodHeader::GetCodeSize() const+380)
    runtime.cc:655] #07 pc 00543367  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+1591)
    runtime.cc:655] #08 pc 006a0897  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+1015)
    runtime.cc:655] #09 pc 0069a171  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+65)
    runtime.cc:655] #10 pc 006c61b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1172)
    runtime.cc:655] #11 pc 006bf266  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+630)
    runtime.cc:655] #12 pc 006be1ce  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+2446)
    runtime.cc:655] #13 pc 0065227d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+445)
    runtime.cc:655] #14 pc 0063984f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1967)
    runtime.cc:655] #15 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
    runtime.cc:655] #16 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
    runtime.cc:655] #17 pc 00006291  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_call_aborter+33)
    runtime.cc:655] #18 pc 00014d14  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+436)
    runtime.cc:655] #19 pc 00405dd0  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+2912)
    runtime.cc:655] #20 pc 00405e64  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+116)
    runtime.cc:655] #21 pc 003f60d3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+67)
    runtime.cc:655] #22 pc 003f4c3d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType)+3837)
    runtime.cc:655] #23 pc 003f34e9  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType*)+969)
    runtime.cc:655] #24 pc 003d76de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+798)
    runtime.cc:655] #25 pc 000129e0  /data/app/~~t5l2JrENqDtK9h63QUieEA==/com.dji.importSDKDemo-GFVSkrTLxiIA3Acvo_NODg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (???)
    runtime.cc:655] #26 pc 00016e36  /data/app/~~t5l2JrENqDtK9h63QUieEA==/com.dji.importSDKDemo-GFVSkrTLxiIA3Acvo_NODg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (JNI_OnLoad+16214)
    runtime.cc:655] #27 pc 0040a488  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, _jclass*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+3832)
    runtime.cc:655] #28 pc 000052a2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+402)
    runtime.cc:655] #29 pc 000299d6  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdk.so (Runtime_nativeLoad+38)
    runtime.cc:655] #30 pc 000828da  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+234)
    runtime.cc:655] #31 pc 001423af  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (???)
    runtime.cc:655] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9106 (i.importSDKDemo), pid 9106 (i.importSDKDemo)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:49352', transport: 'socket'
```

MApplication class

```
package com.dji.importSDKDemo;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import com.secneo.sdk.Helper;

public class MApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context paramContext) {
        super.attachBaseContext(paramContext);
        Helper.install(MApplication.this);
    }

}
```

MainActivity class:

```
package com.dji.importSDKDemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import dji.common.error.DJIError;
import dji.common.error.DJISDKError;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseComponent;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseProduct;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKInitEvent;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    public static final String FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE = "dji_sdk_connection_change";
    private static BaseProduct mProduct;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    };
    private List<String> missingPermission = new ArrayList<>();
    private AtomicBoolean isRegistrationInProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // When the compile and target version is higher than 22, please request the following permission at runtime to ensure the SDK works well.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkAndRequestPermissions();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialize DJI SDK Manager
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is any missing permissions, and
     * requests runtime permission if needed.
     */
    private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        // Check for permissions
        for (String eachPermission : REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, eachPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermission.add(eachPermission);
            }
        }
        // Request for missing permissions
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            showToast("Need to grant the permissions!");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    missingPermission.toArray(new String[missingPermission.size()]),
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Result of runtime permission request
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // Check for granted permission and remove from missing list
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            for (int i = grantResults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    missingPermission.remove(permissions[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        // If there is enough permission, we will start the registration
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else {
            showToast("Missing permissions!!!");
        }
    }

    private void startSDKRegistration() {
        if (isRegistrationInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("registering, pls wait...");

                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                            if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                                showToast("Register Success");
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                            } else {
                                showToast("Register sdk fails, please check the bundle id and network connection!");
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, djiError.getDescription());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProductDisconnect() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onProductDisconnect");
                            showToast("Product Disconnected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProductConnect newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                            showToast("Product Connected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProductChanged(BaseProduct baseProduct) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComponentChange(BaseProduct.ComponentKey componentKey, BaseComponent oldComponent,
                                                      BaseComponent newComponent) {

                            if (newComponent != null) {
                                newComponent.setComponentListener(new BaseComponent.ComponentListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onComponentConnectivityChanged: " + isConnected);
                                        notifyStatusChange();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    String.format("onComponentChange key:%s, oldComponent:%s, newComponent:%s",
                                            componentKey,
                                            oldComponent,
                                            newComponent));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onInitProcess(DJISDKInitEvent djisdkInitEvent, int i) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDatabaseDownloadProgress(long l, long l1) {

                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void notifyStatusChange() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500);
    }

    private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

    private void showToast(final String toastMsg) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dji.importSDKDemo">

<!-- Permissions and features -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Permissions and features -->

<application
    android:name=".MApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- DJI SDK -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
        android:value="44f69f72e43d82a01b14aa97" />

    <!-- DJI SDK -->

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            // On x86 devices that run Android API 23 or above, if the application is targeted with API 23 or
            // above, FFmpeg lib might lead to runtime crashes or warnings.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.11', {
        /**
         * Uncomment the "library-anti-distortion" if your app does not need Anti Distortion for Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom.
         * Uncomment the "fly-safe-database" if you need database for release, or we will download it when DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp
         * is called.
         * Both will greatly reducing the size of the APK.
         */
        exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion'
        //exclude module: 'fly-safe-database'
    })
    compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.11'

    androidTestCompile('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
}

// Please uncomment the following code if you use your own sdk version.
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_all.gradle"
```

graddle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Hello, just wondering if you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code into the proguard-rules.pro file. The code was taken from the dji examples. It helped me.

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,*Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn dji.**
-dontwarn com.dji.**
-dontwarn sun.**
-dontwarn java.**
-dontwarn com.amap.api.**
-dontwarn com.here.**
-dontwarn com.mapbox.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static <methods>;
}

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-keep class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep,allowshrinking class * extends dji.publics.DJIUI.** {
    public <methods>;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }

-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.* { *; }

-keep class dji.** { *; }

-keep class com.dji.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }

-keep,allowshrinking class org.** { *; }

-keep class com.squareup.wire.** { *; }

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-keep class com.secneo.** { *; }

-keep class org.greenrobot.eventbus.**{*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Service
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep class android.** {*;}
-keep class android.media.** { *; }
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keep class com.lmax.disruptor.** {
    *;
}

-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine
-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.MockLocationEngine
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
# ViewModel's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
# keep Lifecycle State and Event enums values
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
# keep methods annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent even if they seem to be unused
# (Mostly for LiveData.LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChange(), but who knows)
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.arch.**
-ignorewarnings
```